# Unexpected Huge Data Transfer On Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am having ec2 instance on Amazon with a website hosted on it. My problem is I am seeing huge data transfer from my machine. There seems to be some hackers downloading and uploading huge data. What is the solution to stop this data transfer. Below is the summary from bill. I have port 80 and port 22 open on internet to connect my machine from anywhere.

```
AWS Data Transfer USW2-APN1-AWS-Out-Bytes
$0.000 per GB - data transfer out under the monthly global free tier    5,e-7.000000 GB
```

Comment: Why is it open to connect from anywhere? Do you want it like that?

Comment: I dont have static ip, I get dynamic ip everytime I connect to internet. That's why I need to keep it open for all ips. Can we give multiple static ips to connect from?

Comment: Yes, you can create more than one rule. If you think your machine will be assigned an IP from a standard pool, you can create a rule for each of them or each subnet. Another option is to change the value from AWS dashboard. Yjird option, if you are familiar with AWS CLI, you can run the CLI with your new IP which open the machine for your new IP

Answer (score 1):

"5,e-7.000000" is actually referring to a very small bandwidth traffic, and reflects a bug in amazon aws interface. I doubt someone hacked your ec2 instance.

see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7996